# Finder Sync plugin and NSXPCConnection

Tags: cocoa, finder, xpc, findersync, osx-extensions

I have the following situation:

- there is a main, non-sandboxed application;
- there is a Finder Sync plugin, bundled into this application. Sandboxed;
- there is a XPC helper bundled into this application. Sandboxed.

Problem: opening `NSXPCConnection` from main application to XPC helper works fine.
However, I cannot connect to it from the Finder Sync plugin, and do not receive any error information (just callback 'Connection invalidated' right after trying to open it).

Am I doing something wrong, or this should be done in other way? For instance, by moving XPC helper to the separate application? Some problems with entitlements?

Comment: Update: I ended up with using mach ports (NSMachPort/NSBootstrapServer/NSMachPortDelegate). It works well.

Comment: Are you still getting this issue ?